# ASP.NET membership provider can't connect to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to use the ASP.NET Membership provider, so I ran `aspnet_regsql.exe` and my tables were created. But after opening the Web Site Administration Tool (ASP.net Setting) page, when I want to add a rule, I get this error:

> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:
>   Unable to connect to SQL Server database.
>   at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.CallWebAdminHelperMethod(Boolean isMembership, String methodName, Object[] parameters, Type[] paramTypes)
>   at ASP.security_users_adduser_aspx.PopulateCheckboxes() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\Security\Users\addUser.aspx:line 28
>   at ASP.security_users_adduser_aspx.Page_Load() in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles\Security\Users\addUser.aspx:line 22
>   at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)  > at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

After googling I found that my connection string may be the problem so my connection string in my `web.config` is like this :

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="authentication" 
        connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa; password=###" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   <add name="EducationDBEntities" 
        connectionString="metadata=res://*/EducationModel.csdl|res://*/EducationModel.ssdl|res://*/EducationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa; password=#######;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"  
        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

And here is my provider code:

```
<membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="authentication" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
```

Here you can see my web.config

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="authentication" 
          connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa; password=####" 
          providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
     <add name="EducationDBEntities" 
          connectionString="metadata=res://*/EducationModel.csdl|res://*/EducationModel.ssdl|res://*/EducationModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=EducationDB;User ID=sa; password=####;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
          providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="authentication" />
      </providers>
    </membership>

  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServerCompact.SqlCeProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
      <add name="Microsoft SQL Server Compact Data Provider 4.0" invariant="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" description=".NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact" type="System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeProviderFactory, System.Data.SqlServerCe, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

I use the MVC4 membership provider and i think it causes the problem .Can i remove the first line?

```
 public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("authentication", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        }
    }
```

Best regards - I am using ASP.NET MVC4

Comment: Unwise to share the `sa` password to your database with the general public.

Comment: just to be sure..you are using sql server not other DBMS right

Comment: Yes i am using sql server

Comment: you may need to change "Data Source" in connectionString. try .\instanceName

Comment: What did write as data source?

Comment: My datasource is local machine

Comment: did you try adding defaultProvider property to <membership node>? <membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">

Comment: @Slava No i don't know how can i do this ?

Comment: `<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="authentication" />
      </providers>
    </membership>`

Comment: @Slava it doesn't work