# set config file for custom role and membership provider causes an error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I want to use custom membership and role provider in MVC4 .

So i added some code to my config file as you can see here:

```
<membership defaultProvider="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider"> 
  <providers> <clear /> 
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="authentication" />

    </providers> 
    </membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" 
       connectionStringName="authentication"
       enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" 
       requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" writeExceptionsToEventLog="false" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

But when i go to ** Web Site Administration Too** for adding role i got this error:

```
The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Sections must only appear once per config file. See the help topic for exceptions. (C:\Users\ehsan\Desktop\EducationModel\EducationMVC\web.config line 46)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple membership providers defined separately:

Removing one of them should get rid of that error. But if you need to have both providers then update as follows:

```
<membership defaultProvider="MembershipProvider2">
<providers>
<add name="MembershipProvider1" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
<add name="MembershipProvider2" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />  
</providers>
</membership>
```

Here MembershipProvider2 is set as defaultProvider just for example. You would update this with whichever providers you need to use as default.

Comment: Yes,how can i combine them as an one sextion .i googled it but i couldn't find that

Comment: i think this will help

Comment: this answer doesn't include role provider

Comment: you'd need to modify your config again for role providers and apply similar change that you applied to membership provider

Comment: You know i am not so expert ,but i got this error because of that i try to include role connection in my webconfig.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226969/asp-net-membership-provider-cant-connect-to-database